What makes a dialect a prestige dialect?
The dialect of upper-class Brits has been considered a prestige dialect not only in the U.K., but also all over the English-speaking world.  Even today, kitchen gadgets are often hawked on American T.V. by a native British English speaker.
But then as somebody said on twitter:
"British accents used to make one sound smart.
Now it’s just an indication of pathos."
Is the prestige of a dialect only reflective of the wealth and power of its speakers?

Nancy Mitford said U and Non-U speakers. https://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/articles/3qF356d7d2D6h98CdCWxf8z/ten-words-that-prove-you-arent-posh#:~:text=U%20refers%20to%20upper%20class,merely%20aspiring%20to%20be%20so. And these ain't dialects. Cockney (Essex) is a dialect. "prestige dialect" is not a subject in linguistics.

@Lambie "Prestige dialect" is definitely a term widely used in linguistics discussion of prestige.

Hilarious bit about prestige speech/behavior.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xzp7Y4mCr2E&t=1063s

https://kkgpublications.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/ijhss.4.10004-5.pdf The term prestige dialect is on the out and out. Sociology is a different story.

@Lambie Cockney and Essex are two very different dialects
